# Boost regex too complex

Tags: python, regex, boost

I want to process a HTML ebook that is huge. I wrote an app in C# that does that just fine, but I would rather do that in Notepad++ with Python script. So I wrote the simplest regex and it throws:

> The complexity of matching the regular expression exceeded predefined bounds.  Try refactoring the regular expression to make each choice made by the state machine unambiguous.  This exception is thrown to prevent "eternal" matches that take an indefinite period time to locate.

I'm not interested in changing my regex, and I don't care about performance. Where do I find those "predefined bounds" so I can change them, or how do I go around it, in case it's not possible?

Edit: here's the piece of code with regex:

```
editor.rereplace("li .+\}", "", re.S )
```

Comment: It might help us to see the regex, even if you are set on it being left unchanged.

Comment: Saying you don't care about performance is kind of silly, since the program is warning you that the match could literally take forever due to infinite recursion.  Your current regex pattern doesn't specify a lazy match for the `.+`, meaning that the match will continue until the last `\}` it sees.  If every `li` element is on its own line and multiline matching is defaulted to off, then this wouldn't create a problem, but this could be part of what you're experiencing now.  Also, the space in between `li` and `.+\}` is unnecessary since `.` matches ` ` as well.  Consider `li.+?\}` instead.

Comment: It will not take forever because it's already tested. I don't want a lazy match because it won't get things done. This question is not about my regex pattern!

Comment: @Caustin: OP probably does not want to match for example "lid" so the space is good to keep

Comment: Can you try with python module "re" instead of Notepad module? (You can still use notepad module to extract the text).

Comment: @seb, yes it works just fine. But I would rather use the BOOST, so I don't have to rewrite the editor text every time.

Comment: OK, so your question is not a python question at all then?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the question is, as there's only one question mark. You answered it, by giving me an idea of a workaround. It works, and it can stay like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[CAustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348112/caustin) has given the right answer here already, but without explaining the reason why greedy expression `li .+\}` resulted in the message about exceeding predefined bounds. Well, I also don't know the exact reason as this would require analyzing the find with debugging into the replace function itself.

However, this expression matches a string starting with `li` and a space and ending on **last** closing brace either on current line or if dot matches also carriage return and line-feeds in entire string respectively file.

This is problematic if the string or like here the file on which the find is executed is very large, let's say several MB or even several GB, and the string / file does not contain any line terminating characters or the dot matches also those characters.

Such a greedy expression can easily result in allocating more and more of free memory just for the found string until there is not enough free memory anymore on the machine which would result in crashes respectively memory exceptions of nearly all running applications on this machine because no more free memory available anymore.

Users of modern PCs with several GB of RAM usually used mainly for file caching and not for the running applications always wonder why such error messages occur on running regular expression finds/replaces within a script or program as there is so much free RAM in total.

Well, 4 GB of free memory in total does not mean that a continuous block of 4 GB is available. Task managers do not show how fragmented the RAM is. And 32-bit applications cannot allocate more than 2 GB of RAM in total because of not being able to address more, except if coded especially for usage of more than 2 GB which is very rare. It can happen very easily that with 2 GB of free RAM in total, it is not possible to allocate 32 MB as a continuous block.

But the developers of the regular expression functions and libraries need to take more into account than PCs used by a single user just running a few applications at same time. Their functions and libraries are also used on embedded devices which have just a few MB of total RAM. And regular expressions are used by many scripts on webservers which have to handle hundreds or even thousands of users at the same time. Servers could be killed very easily if it would be possible by simple greedy regular expressions to allocate several MB of RAM from server - 8 MB for found string x 2000 finds = server killed.

Therefore the total number of bytes a string found by a regular expression can be is limited to just some KB. I don't know the boundary. I have tried once to find it out, but get different results for different finds. It is not a simple **x** KB or **x** MB. There are several other limitations also included like maximum number of recursion (stack overflow prevention) or perhaps also a maximum processing time (keep applications responsive). I really don't know what the developers of the regular expression functions and libraries have included to prevent kills of applications or entire machines caused by a regular expression find/replace.

Therefore lazy (non greedy) expressions by using a question mark after `*` or `+`  should be always preferred over greedy expressions.

If a greedy expression is wanted, it should be limited by the user by using `{min,max}` instead of `*` (0 or more) or `+` (1 or more).

Therefore some possible solutions are here:

- `(?-s)li .+?\}` ... non greedy, single line.
- `(?s)\bli\b.+?\}` ... non greedy, multiple lines.
- `\bli [^}\r\n]\}` ... non greedy, single line.
- `(?s)li .{1,16384}\}` ... greedy, multiple lines.

But even a non greedy expression can result in a message warning about exceeding predefined bounds if the string or file is of undetermined size and undetermined data on which the expression is applied.

Take a look on `(?s)li .+?\}` and think about a file which for example has 8 GB, but has somewhere at beginning `li`  and nowhere or somewhere at end `}`.

The solution is the last expression in the list which is a greedy expression, but stops parsing for closing brace after 16384 characters after having `li`  already found. Therefore the greedy expression `(?s)li .{1,16384}\}` is more secure on usage on undetermined data of undetermined size than the 3 other non greedy expressions in the list above.

---

`(?s)` at beginning of the regular expression enables matching newlines by dot, i.e. turns on multiline mode behavior. So independent on internal default, the `.` matches now also carriage returns and line-feeds, i.e. multiple lines can be matched.

`(?-s)` is the opposite. It disables multiline and enables singleline mode matching behavior for dot.

See the pages:

- [Boost Perl Regular Expression Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) documentation for version 1.55, chapter *Modifiers*
- [Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)
- [XRegExp - Flags](http://xregexp.com/flags/)

The support for mode changing flags within a regular expression search strings depends on the used library and the used version.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does (?s) do?